# No menubar in Xmonad with Ubuntu Unity

Tags: xmonad

when I use xmonad in ubuntu, I follow the tutorial of Xmonad, but there's no app menubar.
How can I solve this problem?

my configure file is here:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
import System.IO
--import XMonad.Config.Gnome
import XMonad.Layout.Gaps
myLayouts = gaps [(U, 24)] -- $ layoutHook gnomeConfig 


main = do
--  xmproc <- spawnPipe "/usr/bin/xmobar ~/.xmobarrc"
xmonad $ defaultConfig
{manageHook = composeAll [
    -- other hooks,
    manageDocks
    , className =? "Unity-2d-panel"    --> doIgnore
    --, className =? "Unity-2d-launcher" --> doIgnore
      -- more hooks
    ]

    -- for gnome begin
    --manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
    -- for gnome end
, layoutHook = avoidStruts  $  layoutHook defaultConfig
--, logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
--                    { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
--                    , ppTitle = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 50
--                    }
, modMask = mod4Mask     -- Rebind Mod to the Windows key
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you figure it out, it's really annoying.

Comment: This might be useful: https://gist.github.com/1300108

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to remove global appmenu bar, indicator-appmenu.

You can remove it using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

then logout/login.  Note that this is global so all accounts will loose the global appmenu.

Comment: This works, but I'd prefer if it actually used the shared menu.

Comment: What would probably be ideal (at least for an ubunutu/xmonad world) would be a menubar for xmonad that works nicely with the indicator-appmenu global menu bar.  Otherwise it's just a topic for arguments: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/734325

Answer (score 0):

XMonad does not have a menubar, but there are plenty bar's out there. If you have a Gnome installed, you could use the `gnome-panel` as a first start.

Other menubar's that work well with XMonad are:

- [xmobar](http://projects.haskell.org/xmobar/)
- [dzen](https://sites.google.com/site/gotmor/dzen)
- [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I know XMonad has No menu, I mean the menu bar of every application.In gnome2, it's ok. but in unity, it uses global menu bar, it doesn't work well with xmonad

Comment: when I don't start unity-panel in the configure file, the app menu appears. anyway, thankyou.

Comment: what about the program starter, that comes up normally via alt+p?